# Взятие сообщения по id в telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

В библиотеке telebot Python есть возможность взять `id` некоторого сообщения. Можно ли, зная `id` взять некоторое сообщение с этим `id`?

upd: pyTelegramBotAPI https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: Уточните какой конкретно телебот имеется ввиду - их очень много. Добавьте ссылку на либу

Comment: Нет никакой возможности получить старые, уже обработанные, сообщения, используя Telegram Bot API. Нужно запоминать входящие сообщения, если хотите потом их как-то обрабатывать

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее, для чего необходимо сообщение по id, т.е. какие именно параметры данного сообщения Вам нужны.

Comment: Текст сообщения

Comment: дружище, если ты спустя столько лет узнал как это сделать, ответь пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант использовать copy_message

```
message = bot.copy_message(chat_id, from_chat_id, message_id)
text = message.text
```

В качестве chat_id можно использовать любой другой канал(например для тестирования) где бот может слать сообщения. При необходимости после copy_message можно сразу выполнить `delete_message(chat_id, message.message_id)`, чтобы удалить только что скопированное сообщение.